# sklearn classifier on device motion data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The idea is this:
I’ve collected accelerometer and gyroscope xyz data from my iPhone.
This dat is collected per gesture a user makes with the phone like drawing a circle/box/cross in the air.
This data is organised per gesture Type in a csv file per gesture recording. To be clear, a single recording is stored in a single csv file.

So we have the labelled data now.

I know how to create a classifier on text reviews labelled with positive negative. But I can’t figure out how to create a classifier based on 6 values (accelerometer and gyroscope xyz) in multiple recordings.

Where can I learn this or does someone have a clear example?
And what are the steps I need to take to program this classifier

Comment: There have been a Capstone project on Coursera Data Science Specialization (batch 1 or 2) like this. The data was from gyroscope and accelerometer attached to neck, hands, legs and waste of gym attendants. The resulting accuracy was 99%+. I believe there must be a similar dataset on [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php) or somewhere on the web.

Comment: Do you know where i Can find that?

Answer (score 0):

See Github repo for a similar project in `R` here:

https://github.com/sbushmanov/GnCD_Course_Project